# AngularJS/UIRouter: Route change doesn't update view until controller of target state is finished executing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app with UI router.

I am in a view where I have a `ui-sref` going to my route:

```
<a ng-href="#" ui-sref="app.myRoute">Next</a>
```

The route I am going to loads a controller that performs a long task on loading:

```
app.controller('MyRouteController', function($scope) {
    this.load = function() {
       // ... make a long service call
    };

    this.load();
});
```

The behavior that I see is that upon clicking the `ui-sref` link, the view does not change until after the `load()` method is finished executing. This is true even if wrapping the `load()` call in a `$timeout`.

How can I make the view change right away and make the `load()` call asynchronous to loading the view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should wait for `load` to finish while it is called synchronously. [And it shouldn't (and it won't)](http://plnkr.co/edit/khScTgi6epMRwWjCuJHJ?p=preview) while it is called with `$timeout`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url:'/',
        template: '<div ng-controller="AppController"></div>',
        controller: function ($timeout) {
          console.log('route controller')
          $timeout(function () {
            console.log('route controller timeout')
          })
        }
    })
    .state('otherwise', {
        url: "*path",
        template: '<a ui-sref="root">root</a>'
    });
});

app.controller('AppController', function () {
  console.log('app controller')
});
```